# Webstorm remote file path is not mapped

Tags: tfs, webstorm

I have set up a project from a TFS server account. After mapping the required folders for my development, i have created a project on Webstrom and then configured the TFS (with TFS plugin) to work accordingly.

I can sync and get files easily, however, once I try to write on the files (since it's all read-only till used), an error saying: "Cannot edit file(s): Mapping not found for files:"

Comment: please check https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-142964 - does it look similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test pass in my lab environment(Webstorm11.0.1  TFS2015).
[image]

Just right click the file in project, **select TFS -select Edit**. After doing this ,it will check out the file from TFS server automatically and be editable.

Could you still see your mapping workspace under **'Manage TFS Servers and Workspaces**'and your project under **Working folders**?
Below is my personal settings for your reference:

Make sure three things:

- You are working on the **Server workspace**.
- The status of the working folders should be **Active**.
- **Your TFS server account have the edit and check out Permissions of this project in TFS server.**

[image]

If it still doesn't work, please [check the log](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1202) (Help-show log in..) whether contains any clues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I no longer receive that error, however, When checking out files, I don't see them being checked out on where I manage TFS (eclipse), therefore, can't check in my files in there. I think I will try to find a better solution/combination. I will accept your answer as it did help get rid of the error.